# PHP and API calls performance and best practices in one to many relationship

Tags: php, android, mysql, performance, api

We have a server with a elearning webpage which stores data into a MySQL database. There are three main entities: `elearning (id, name, description)`, 
`question (id, elearning_id, question)` and `answer (id, question_id, text, isCorrect)`. Therefore, the relationship between elearning with question and question
with answer is one to many. Now, I'm developing an API to make these database accessible
from an Android app. In order to **get** these data, I have in mind to create one file, "elearnings.php", which gets an elearning_id and returns
all the questions and answers of this elearning. When the user answers the questions through the Android side, I need to **store** them into the database.
Let's say that I need to store five answers for the current elearning package. Which option is better, in terms of performance and best practices? What is the
usual way to do it?

**A)** To create a php file `save_answers.php` which **gets all the answers in an array**, so it is only necessary to make **one http call** from the Android 
side to the API. However, the server side is in charge of processing the array.

**B)** To create a php file `save_answers.php` which **gets only one answer**, so in this case it would be necessary to make **five http calls** from the Android 
side to the API. In this case, the server side does not need to process any arrays of answers.

Thanks!

Comment: this question will attract opinions ... and not really fit for this forum. In the opinion department : create a `save_selected_answers.php` file, and cumulate in the app the questions that have been answered and the answer. Server side, only save those.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i would suggest using a framework for your API, 
[Laravel](https://laravel.com/)
Is probably the best one for that.

A framework will improve security of your app, easily connect to your database, provide helpful librairy for development and much more. You should lookup for how to make a good REST API also, just to make sure you start on a solid base. It will also insure that you use the MVC model for your app, which is the best.

For your problem, i suggest you make a function called ( for exemple ) SetInfo In your controller Comment, which take a user Id, a question Id, a comment and more data you wish to store.

```
public function SetComment(){
    //retreive JSON info
    $data = json_decode($_POST['data'])
    //validate your data
    // insert in the database.
}
```

I suggest having one comment by request, it's easier to process and validate.

Comment: Hi @Nicolas! Thanks for your answer! First of all, I will take a look at Laravel framework. On the other hand, I agree with you that for the server side is better to have only one answer by request, because as you have said, it's easier to process and validate. What about the Android app performance? Do you think that if I make five http requests instead one this performance will be affected? Thanks again!

Comment: i don't think it will change something, the request you make arn't big enought to make a big diffrence. you will have to keep them in memory until you have 5 messages to send. which could be hard to manage.